# Mongoose,Socket.IO - cannot get print empty string if result is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I have a filter using socket.io and mongoose. I try to print out something if there is no result return when querying but it doesn't work.

```
Restaurant.find({ $text : { $search : query } },
            { score : { $meta: "textScore" } })
            .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } }).exec(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results)
            if (!results){
                console.log(results)
            }
```

It prints out two empty arrays to console. The first empty array is printed by the first `console.log` when the page finishes loading. The second empty array is printed out when I click filter button with an empty search. When I delete the first `console.log`, nothing printed out. The `console.log` inside the if condition is never be executed.

I tried `results == []` and `results == null` but it still doesn't work. It works fine when there is a result, however. Can anyone explain why this happens and suggest a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find will result with an array, you should check the array length

`results.length > 0`

Comment: How come I didn't think of it. Thanks a lot!